# I can't bind the ` (tilde) key as hotkey for DoTA 2 scoreboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm using English (US,alt,intl) and for whatever reason the game doesn't recognize when I use the <kbd>`</kbd> key. Any other keys work fine. Of course, changing my keyboard input to another language made the button where my <kbd>`</kbd>  is be something else and it works but it's annoying to switch languages. Any ideas how to use tilde in DoTA 2?

Answer (score 0):

With the US international keyboard after your having typed the <kbd>`</kbd> key the keyboard waits for the next character to decide whether you want to type an <kbd>è</kbd>, <kbd>à</kbd> or another letter with an accent grave. If you want to type a single <kbd>`</kbd> you have to add a space.

Therefore this key is not suited as a hotkey with this keyboard.

You have the same problem with <kbd>~</kbd>, as there are letters like <kbd>ñ</kbd> that can be typed with the US international keyboard.